# Instagram Python API subscribe to tags on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, instagram

I am working on a project, where I want to be able to retrieve real-time updates if users upload a picture on Instagram with a specific tag (a custom action should be executed when a user uploads a picture with a specific tag). The whole thing should be written in Python and should be running on a stand-alone Raspberry Pi.

As far as I have understood the Python Instagram API sends a GET request to the specified callback url which needs to respond with the hub.challenge parameter and so on. This means that the Python Script needs to run on the Server that is also hosting the callback url right? Which would mean that I can not do this on a Raspberry Pi.

Am I missing something here? I also built a similar thing with the Twitter Streaming API and it was not a problem at all!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you successfully used twitter on raspberry (I did it also, with Twython, which was fun), you can just use [ifttt](http://www.ifttt.com) to send a tweet automatically each time there's a new photo on instagram. With the raspberry, you can check for new tweets regularly.